# Prove for x in Hilbert space, C is closed convex subset of Hilbert space, exist one point $x'$ s.t. $||x-x'|| \le \inf\{||x'' - x||:x''\in C\}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, i.e. inner product space and complete. $C$ is a closed convex subset of $H$. For $x \in H$, show that there is a unique $x'\in C$ such that 
$$||x-x'|| \le \inf\{||x'' - x||:x''\in C\}$$

My idea is that this is same as showing $<x-x',c> = 0, \forall c\in C$, which have can be done if $C$ is complete. And I think convex subset of a complete space should be also complete since it have to content all points in between of any two points in the set. So if I can show that convex subset of a complete space also complete then I am done but I was not be able to show that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement in the title is not true. The real line is  Hilbert space and $(0,1)$ is a convex set. If $x=0$ there is no $x' \in(0 ,1)$ such that $|x-0| \leq\inf \{|x''-x|: x''\in (0,1)\}$. [ The infimum is $0$].

If $C$ is a closed convex set then the conclusion is true and it is one of the first theorem that anyone proves in the theory of Hilbert spaces. Ref. Rudin's RCA, Simmons topology, etc.

Also, a convex subset of a complete space need not be complete, an obvious example being $(0,1)$ in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Is a closed convex subset of a complete space complete? And thank you to point out the error in title

Comment: @Awoo Any closed subset of a complete metric space is complete. This has nothing to do with convexity.

Comment: That is very helpful! Thank you.